# Remove URL field from Links list using powershell

Tags: powershell, links-list

I need to remove URL field from `Links` list using PowerShell. Is there any way to remove. I think it need to be deleted from Content type. But I just need to remove the reference.

Answer (score 1):

URL field is mandatory in Links content type. If want to remove it from content type you won’t get the option to remove/delete. I suggest you to hide the URL field instead of removing because removing from content type will impact other links content type list.

Here is the code to set hidden

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity http://your/site/name 
$list = $web.Lists["Your List Name"] 
$column = $list.Fields["Your Column Name"] 
$column.Hidden = $true
$column.ReadOnlyField = $true 
$column.Update() 
$list.Update()
```